# Searching for a pattern in a string using base python not biopython

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics, python-re, fasta

I am working on a problem (tutorial question) where I have to work on a fasta file. I had to create a function that reads the fasta file. The function that I created is called `readind_fasta_file`. After that I had to import that function into the new script and perform the task of searching that pattern. I am stuck because it says `NameError: name 'reading_fasta_file' is not defined` and I do not know where I may have gone wrong since I am beginner in python. The instruction is to not use biopython.

```
import re
from reading_fasta_file import*

infiles = "Sequence.fasta"  
match_list = []  
pattern = "[YFWLIMVA]..[LMALVN]..[AGSTCD].[LAIVNFYMW]"

for infile in infiles:
    sequence_data = reading_fasta_file(infiles)  #
    for lines in sequence_data:
        matches = re.finditer(pattern, lines)
        for m in matches:
            match_id = f'{m.start()}_{m.end()}_{m.group()}'  # 
            match_list.append(match_id)  #load our matches into our empty list
```

My expected output would be something like this as an example:
where 1 is the start position and 10 end position

1  10 LFFLAATGN

Comment: In what file do you have your function 'reading_fasta_file'?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg the file name is reading_fasta_file.py

Comment: So you need just to  correctly import the module from current directory.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I want to import ```reading_fasta_file()```, which is in the ```reading_fasta_file.py``` into my new file which is ```pattern_search.py```. Both files are in the same working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect.

If you import a module, like `import math`, the module's name is defined, you can use the functions it provides, but the module itself isn't callable.

You can use `math.gcd` for example to get the greatest common denominator of integers, but you can't use `math` as a function. If you want to use only `gcd` then you do `from math import gcd` and when you want to use `gcd` you call `gcd`.

Example, to get the `gcd` of 24 and 50:

```
import math
print(math.gcd(24, 50))
```

Or:

```
from math import gcd
print(gcd(24, 50))
```

In the first example, `math` is defined and you can use all its members by using `math` plus `.` and the name of the member you want to use. In the second case `math` is undefined and you can only use `gcd`.
In all cases you always call `gcd`, never `math`. `math(24, 50)` doesn't work and has no meaning at all.

In your case, you didn't define `reading_fasta_file`, so it isn't defined. But if you import it like the first example, then you will get:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

You can never call a module, instead call the function it provides.

Suppose you have a function named `foo` that is provided by `reading_fasta_file`, if you want to call `foo`, use either of the following:

```
import reading_fasta_file
reading_fasta_file.foo(*args)
```

Or

```
from reading_fasta_file import foo
foo(*args)
```

Since you haven't provided the code of `reading_fasta_file` I can't help you further. But your method of using modules is wrong and that is what's causing this problem.